# Macbuntu 10.10 installation via command line

Tags: command-line, system-installation, macbuntu

I have edited the install.sh file and I'm trying to install Macbuntu 10.10 via command line with the following:

```
sashi@Sashi-System-Product-Name:~$ cd Macbuntu10.10
bash: cd: Macbuntu10.10: No such file or directory
sashi@Sashi-System-Product-Name:~$ cd Macbuntu-10.10
sashi@Sashi-System-Product-Name:~/Macbuntu-10.10$ sudo atp-get install ./install.sh
```

However, it isn't installing.  What should I do?

Comment: Are you *in* the correct directory?..

Answer (score 1):

From looking over the instructions [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/09/make-ubuntu-look-like-mac-osx-in.html) it seems the install script `install.sh` should do everything for you.  So you don't need to do `apt-get` stuff.  In other words, from inside the directory, just type `./install.sh`

That's it!

Comment: Yes, this is not working, its saying No permission

bash: ./install.sh: Permission denied

Comment: Oh, first do `chmod +x install.sh` and then `./install.sh`